# Configure chain parameters (epoch/era/bondig/etc) for dev node?

Tags: testing, dev-node

I'm trying to run some rpc tests for staking. I'm using the polkadot binary with `--dev`, which works reasonably well, except that the epoch/bonding timings are way too long for testing/development. I can't seem to set these via the command line parameters. I also tried `polkadot build-spec --dev`, but the resulting json doesn't seem to have these parameters, or at least that I can recognize.

Is there an easy way to configure the chain parameters (most of the things found here: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-polkadot-parameters) for a dev node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cargo build --release --features fast-runtime
```

Comment: Thanks. I compiled with the `fast-runtime` feature and it created a binary with faster epoch/era/etc times. Then I looked in the code and the values for various parameters can be configured at compile time with environment variables. I don't believe these are documented anywhere. They can be found in `runtime/src/polkadot/lib.rs` by searching for `prod_or_fast`. For example, `DOT_EPOCH_DURATION` sets the epoch duration.