# How can I speed up a local test chain or Customize session | era | epoch values

Tags: validator, specs

I want to test validator/nominate scenarios, like how to stake and earn rewards and get slashed!

However I want to increase the pace at which these events occur, so that as engineers we can iterate over these tests in hours and not days.

Is there already a chainspec for this else how should I accomplish increasing the pace of a local test chain?

Comment: This question provides an adequate answer https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/configure-chain-parameters-epoch-era-bondig-etc-for-dev-node  however I do want to expand on what the new timings will become.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a list of built-in chain specs in this source file, https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/cli/src/command.rs#L84

By compiling polkadot with the fast-runtime feature flag, you can reduce the timings to a 2 min epoch and 12 min Era.

'cargo build --release --features fast-runtime'

Both --chain polkadot-local and kusama-local had the 2min/12min timings.